# Xcode Core Data Attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, attributes, boolean

I'm making an app and have a core data file with an entity and 15 boolean attributes. I want it so that when a user presses a button it changes the value of one of the attributes from "0" to "1" in the core data file. What is the code to do this? I already have the action set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
   myManagedObject.boolAttribute = [NSNumber numberWithBool:
    ![myManagedObject.boolAttribute boolValue]];
   [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
   // if you need to update the UI (no fetchedResultsController):
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; 
   // or
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```